# Adding login failure

Tags: bug, login

### Bug-report

***Chrome***
In Chrome, I am connected to an account `PRO`. 
Say, in SO the account name is `PRO-SO`.

I have also, and would like to add to my accounts an other Google account `PER`, that corresponds to the SO account - `PER-SO`.

I don't need to merge two accounts into one. I need to switch between one to another.

I tough (apparently is not the case) that the "Add login"'s account feature is created for that.

On SO, I am connected as `PRO-SO`. Go to my login page, "Logins"=>"Add login", clicked on "Google",

*Expected* : `add the new account PER (> PER-SO?)`

*Obtained*: `Page not found` (bug, whatever I would like to do)

***IE 11***

In IE, I have no accounts connected. Go to SO, connected as `PRO-SO`.
The rest the same as above:

*Expected* : `add the account PER(SO)`

*Obtained*: `returns to the profile page, does not add a login` (bug, whatever I intended to do)

**NB!**
Please **not set as duplicate**, because ***I don't search a workaround***, but report a bug. The described behavior gives unexpected results (*page not found*) to a valid and legal user's request (adding a login).

Comment: I would suggest you change your note about this not being a duplicate to something along the lines of "The linked question is not relevant to my issue as I am not trying to add two Google logins to one Stack Overflow account, but instead I want to connect two separate Stack Overflow accounts _without merging them_ to make switching between my work account and my personal account easier."